# How to avoid shipping libtool .la file into build package?

Tags: c, linux

Below is makefile:

```
libdir=/usr/lib/test/

lib_LTLIBRARIES = libmain.la

libmainla_SOURCES = main.c
libmain_la_LDFLAGS =  -avoid-version
```

When i built the package, `libmain.la`  file also shipped along with the `libmain.so` into the package.

Could you please let me know how to avoid shipping of `.la` file?

Comment: the posted makefile doesn't do anything.  Please post the rest of the makefile.

Comment: Makefile contains only these lines.. There is no rest of the makefile..